# Apache + Wsgi + Django 2.1 + Virtualenv 3 = Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

So I have had success deploying django applications on python 2.7, but this is my first time trying it with 3.6 and django 2.1, and for some reason apache keeps getting me this error:

```
    [Thu Sep 06 17:23:13.591266 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18011] AH00051: child pid 18164 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
```

I have looked over the internet but cant find a solution.
Here is my VirtualHost:

```
Listen 8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
ServerName mysite.com

WSGIDaemonProcess Project python-home=/home/happyuser/myproject_tst/venv python-path=/home/happyuser/myproject_tst
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/happyuser/myproject_tst/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

ErrorLog /home/happyuser/apache_errors.log

Alias /static /home/happyuser/myproject_tst/myproject/static/

<Directory /home/happyuser/myproject_tst/myproject>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /home/happyuser/myproject_tst/myproject/static>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

LogLevel debug

</VirtualHost>
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated